# Hamburger icon not working for Navigation Architecture Components

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

So I have used the navigation architecture components with java although I followed the codelabds that use kotlin.
My code is working but I have detected a few issues:
1. The hamburger icon is visible but does not work. Sliding the screen from the left displays the navigation drawer.
2. The back button for fragments does not work either.

I thought it is an issue with the toolbar but I do not think so because I have an overflow menu that works just fine.

How do I solve these issues, please? I am so close to figuring this out but I am stuck.

Below is the code.

```
    package com.disruption.globalmail;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    public static String mRequestUrl = "url here";
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private NavController mNavController;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        assert actionBar != null;
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);

        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment);


        assert navHostFragment != null;
        mNavController = navHostFragment.getNavController();


        Set<Integer> topLevelDests = new HashSet<>();
        topLevelDests.add(R.id.top_news_dest);
        topLevelDests.add(R.id.duplicate_top_news_dest);

        mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(topLevelDests)
                .setDrawerLayout(mDrawerLayout)
                .build();

        setupActionBar(mNavController);

        setupNavigationMenu(mNavController);
    }

    private void setupNavigationMenu(NavController navController) {
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    private void setupActionBar(NavController navController) {
        // This allows NavigationUI to decide what label to show in the action bar
        // By using appBarConfig, it will also determine whether to
        // show the up arrow or drawer menu icon
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mDrawerLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, mNavController)
                || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

and the layout below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/news_nav_graph" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_nav_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: UPDATE: The answer by Carson J. below is the correct one as I have marked it. However, I would like to point out that the import statements and the onOptionsItemSelected method are both correct. Adding the onSupportNavigateUp implementation fixed it by passing in the navController and the drawerLayout. However, using Java, this is how I did it:                                        
 `@Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(mNavController, mDrawerLayout);
    }`

Comment: One other thing. I noticed that setting my topLevelDestinations was not working. So I had to pass the mAppBarConfiguration in the setupActionBarWithNavController method. The changed code looks like this :NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);  instead of the above where the last argument is the drawerLayout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
package com.disruption.globalmail;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;

// I'm not sure that you want to use only NavigationUI for 
// some of those methods. Try using these instead.
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.onNavDestinationSelected
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    public static String mRequestUrl = "url here";
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private NavController mNavController;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        assert actionBar != null;
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);

        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment);

        assert navHostFragment != null;
        mNavController = navHostFragment.getNavController();

        Set<Integer> topLevelDests = new HashSet<>();
        topLevelDests.add(R.id.top_news_dest);
        topLevelDests.add(R.id.duplicate_top_news_dest);

        mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(topLevelDests)
            .setDrawerLayout(mDrawerLayout)
            .build();

        setupActionBar(mNavController);

        setupNavigationMenu(mNavController);
    }

    private void setupNavigationMenu(NavController navController) {
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setupWithNavController(navController);
    }

    private void setupActionBar(NavController navController) {
        // This allows NavigationUI to decide what label to show in the action bar
        // By using appBarConfig, it will also determine whether to
        // show the up arrow or drawer menu icon
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, mDrawerLayout);
    }

    // This might just fix your issue by itself.
    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        return navigateUp(mNavController, mDrawerLayout)
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        return item.onNavDestinationSelected(mNavController)
            || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Your problem could be using the wrong navigation methods for setup, but I think this addition might do it for you without having to change those:

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    return navigateUp(mNavController, mDrawerLayout)
}
```

I haven't tried overriding the onCreateOptionsMenu, so I'm not sure if you are doing that correctly. Otherwise, you're definitely on the right track.